# Is there a way to see the scheduled procedures of Application.OnTime on Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I am designing a dashboard-like workbook in Excel and I've created a routine to show some Charts from time to time automatically using the   `Application.OnTime` method from Excel VBA, but I am having some problems debugging my routines.

There are three scheduled routines:
the first takes a snapshot of the data for the charts, the second starts the exhibition of the charts and the third, started by the second, cicles through the charts, showing them for a brief period of time

My main problem is to keep track of the last execution of the routines, because each one of them schedule themselves with `Application.OnTime`

So I have two questions:

One: Is there a way to see the scheduled routines from `Application.OnTime` in Excel?

Two: Is there a better way to schedule repetitive routines using VBA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way that I know to get what is scheduled.  When I was debugging a program that used OnTime, I made my own log so I could see what got scheduled and when.

```
Public Function WriteLog(bSchedule As Boolean) As Boolean

    Dim sFile As String, lFile As Long
    Dim sOutput As String
    Dim bReturn As Boolean

    Const sSOURCE As String = "WriteLog()"

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    bReturn = True

    sFile = Environ("USERPROFILE") & gsLOGPATH & gsTIMERLOG
    lFile = FreeFile

    sOutput = bSchedule
    sOutput = sOutput & "," & gdtNextRun
    sOutput = sOutput & "," & gsSCHEDMACRO
    sOutput = sOutput & "," & Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")

    Open sFile For Append As lFile

    Print #lFile, sOutput

    Close lFile

ErrorExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    WriteLog = bReturn
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    bReturn = False
    If bCentralErrorHandler(msMODULE, sSOURCE) Then
        Stop
        Resume
    Else
        Resume ErrorExit
    End If

End Function
```

This uses an error handling system, so you'll have to fix it up for yours or remove the error handling stuff.

- gdtNextRun is a global date variable for the next scheduled run
- gsSCHEDMACRO is a global string constant for which macro will run
- bSchedule logs whether I'm scheduling or un-scheduling.

If you have multiple OnTimes going, you'll need an array or collection to keep track.  Mine was just one macro either scheduled to run or not, so my global variable/constant did the trick.

Comment: I tried your solution (with a few modifications) and worked very well. Thanks!